# HPacucli sees my MSA1000 in centos5 but not in centos6

Tags: centos, hp, hp-modular-smart-array

I reinstalled my centos5 with centos6 and now I cannot manage my MSA1000 with hpacucli anymore. I can see the /dev/sdX arrays, but hpacucli not cpqacuxe sees the controller on MSA1000.

I still can boot to centos5 and see the controller there, so it is working all right.

```
#### CENTOS 6
$ rpm -qa hp*
hpacucli-8.60-8.0.i386
hponcfg-3.1.1-0.noarch
hpsmh-6.2.1-14.x86_64
hp-health-8.6.2.2-14.x86_64

$ hpacucli    ctrl all show status

Smart Array 6i in Slot 0 (Embedded)
   Controller Status: OK
   Cache Status: OK

$ dmesg
qla2xxx [0000:00:00.0]-0005: QLogic Fibre Channel HBA Driver: 8.04.00.08.06.4-k.
qla2xxx 0000:07:01.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 48 (level, low) -> IRQ 48
qla2xxx [0000:07:01.0]-001d: Found an ISP2312 irq 48 iobase 0xffffc90001870000.
qla2xxx 0000:07:01.0: firmware: requesting ql2300_fw.bin
scsi3 : qla2xxx
qla2xxx [0000:07:01.0]-00fb:3: QLogic QLA2340 - .
qla2xxx [0000:07:01.0]-00fc:3: ISP2312: PCI-X (133 MHz) @ 0000:07:01.0 hdma- host#=3 fw=3.03.27 IPX.
qla2xxx [0000:07:01.0]-505f:3: Link is operational (2 Gbps).
scsi 3:0:0:0: RAID              COMPAQ   MSA1000          4.48 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
scsi 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 12
scsi 3:0:0:1: Direct-Access     COMPAQ   MSA1000 VOLUME   4.48 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
sd 3:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
sd 3:0:0:1: [sda] 3440979568 512-byte logical blocks: (1.76 TB/1.60 TiB)
sd 3:0:0:1: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 3:0:0:1: [sda] Mode Sense: 83 00 00 08
scsi 3:0:0:2: Direct-Access     COMPAQ   MSA1000 VOLUME   4.48 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
sd 3:0:0:1: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
sd 3:0:0:2: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
sd 3:0:0:2: [sdb] 853570592 512-byte logical blocks: (437 GB/407 GiB)
 sda:
sd 3:0:0:2: [sdb] Write Protect is off
sd 3:0:0:2: [sdb] Mode Sense: 83 00 00 08
 unknown partition table
sd 3:0:0:2: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
 sdb:
sd 3:0:0:1: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
 sdb1
sd 3:0:0:2: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk


#### CENTOS 5
$ rpm -qa hp*
hp-ilo-8.5.0-1.rhel5
hp-fc-enablement-1.2-9
hponcfg-4.0.0-0
hp-OpenIPMI-8.5.2-85.rhel5
hpsmh-7.1.0-16
hpacucli-8.70-8.0
hp-health-8.7.0.22-11

$ hpacucli controller all show status

MSA1000 in SGM064686M
   Controller Status: OK
   Cache Status: OK
   Battery/Capacitor Status: OK

Smart Array 6i in Slot 0 (Embedded)
   Controller Status: OK
   Cache Status: OK

$ dmesg
QLogic Fibre Channel HBA Driver
PCI: Enabling device 0000:07:01.0 (0150 -> 0153)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt 0000:07:01.0[A] -> GSI 48 (level, low) -> IRQ 209
qla2xxx 0000:07:01.0: Found an ISP2312, irq 209, iobase 0xffffc2000001e000
qla2xxx 0000:07:01.0: Configuring PCI space...
qla2xxx 0000:07:01.0: Configure NVRAM parameters...
qla2xxx 0000:07:01.0: Verifying loaded RISC code...
qla2xxx 0000:07:01.0: Allocated (412 KB) for firmware dump...
qla2xxx 0000:07:01.0: LIP reset occured (f7f7).
scsi3 : qla2xxx
qla2xxx 0000:07:01.0:
 QLogic Fibre Channel HBA Driver: 8.03.07.15.05.09-k
  QLogic QLA2340 -
  ISP2312: PCI-X (133 MHz) @ 0000:07:01.0 hdma-, host#=3, fw=3.03.26 IPX
qla2xxx 0000:07:01.0: LOOP UP detected (2 Gbps).
  Vendor: COMPAQ    Model: MSA1000           Rev: 4.48
  Type:   RAID                               ANSI SCSI revision: 04
scsi 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 12
  Vendor: COMPAQ    Model: MSA1000 VOLUME    Rev: 4.48
  Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 04
SCSI device sda: 3440979568 512-byte hdwr sectors (1761782 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
sda: Mode Sense: 83 00 00 08
SCSI device sda: drive cache: write back
SCSI device sda: 3440979568 512-byte hdwr sectors (1761782 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
sda: Mode Sense: 83 00 00 08
SCSI device sda: drive cache: write back
 sda: unknown partition table
sd 3:0:0:1: Attached scsi disk sda
sd 3:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
  Vendor: COMPAQ    Model: MSA1000 VOLUME    Rev: 4.48
  Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 04
SCSI device sdb: 853570592 512-byte hdwr sectors (437028 MB)
sdb: Write Protect is off
sdb: Mode Sense: 83 00 00 08
SCSI device sdb: drive cache: write back
SCSI device sdb: 853570592 512-byte hdwr sectors (437028 MB)
sdb: Write Protect is off
sdb: Mode Sense: 83 00 00 08
SCSI device sdb: drive cache: write back
 sdb: sdb1
sd 3:0:0:2: Attached scsi disk sdb
sd 3:0:0:2: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
```

Comment: Guess what, hp-fc-enablement was missing. It rebuild my initrd and now it is working. Silly of me not notifing before.

Answer (score 1):

Guess what, hp-fc-enablement was missing. It rebuild my initrd and now it is working. Silly of me not notifing before.